Почему в VS Installer нет привычных пунктов для установки?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне возможно установить некоторые пункты, почему-то отсутствующие у меня, такие как, например Python development или Desktop development with C++ и, как понимаю, множество других?
Скриншот моей ситуации:

То, как оно, по идее, должно выглядеть:


Второй скриншот от VS2019. Хотя пунктов все равно не хватает.  https://i.sstatic.net/0koW5qiC.png Попробуйте поставить нужное на вкладке отдельные компоненты.
